# Neo4j and php-zts pthreads segfault when trying to run query

Tags: php, multithreading, neo4j

In order to perform some work in the given timeframe i need to use a multi-threaded approach.
I am having issues with executing neo4j queries, any call to `neo4j-php-client->run` yields a segfault.

This is  my thread class:

```
class ABthread  extends Thread {

    private $thread_id;
    private $addr_array;
    private $neo_ip;
    private $neo_timeout;

    public function run() {
        $id = $this->thread_id;
        $addr_array = $this->addr_array;
        $neo_ip = $this->neo_ip;
        $neo_timeout = $this->neo_timeout;
        $neo4j  = ClientBuilder::create()
            -> addConnection('default', $neo_ip)
            -> setDefaultTimeout($neo_timeout)
            -> build();

    $query = "MATCH a....";
        try{
            $result = $neo4j->run ($query);
            } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    public function __construct($id, $array, $neo_ip, $neo_timeout)
        // constructor
    {
        $this->thread_id = $id;
        $this->addr_array = $array;
        $this->neo_ip = $neo_ip;
        $this->neo_timeout = $neo_timeout;

    }
}
```

I get a segfault here: `$result = $neo4j->run ($query);` Any pointers would be appreciated.

(I know PHP is not the ideal multi-threaded language, but i am currently limited to that language)